# Linear boundary value problem $ a(x)u''(x) + b(x)u'(x) = f(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this boundary value problem and need help.

> Let $a,b,f \in L^{\infty}((0,1))$. Assuming that a $\gamma >0$ exists so that $a(x) \geq \gamma $ for almost all $x \in (0,1)$, solve
>   $$a(x)u''(x) + b(x)u'(x) = f(x) \quad\forall x \in (0,1)$$
>   $$u(0)=0,\quad u(1)=1$$
>   *Note*: You should be able to use the identity $h''-g'h' = e^g (e^{-g} h')'$.

How to start? I think you're meant to use the identity at the start and I'm not sure how because the problem doesn't have that form.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Thank you! That's my problem, though, I think you're meant to use the identity at the start and I'm not sure how because the problem doesn't have that form

Comment: Divide by $a(x)$, let $h=u(x)$ and $-g' = b(x)/a(x)$.  Then the left-hand-side does have the form given.